# How to translate "sexy"?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, slang

How would one translate “sexy” into Latin? In particular, I’m looking for a word or phrase that has a similar “slangy” feel to the English version.

I’ve considered a few possibilities: Catullus 10 lead me to the word *invenustum*, and thus to [*venustus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/venustus#Latin) (“attractive”), which seems to be a decent fit. I’ve also considered *voluptuosus* and *sensualis*, but I don’t think they mean quite the same thing as “sexy.”

I also tried to see if modern Italian has a word for “sexy” that could be traced back to Latin, but it seems “sexy” is used as a loanword instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know how in Greek there are three different words for love depending on what exactly you mean? The English 'sexy' is similar. However, the best I can think of is **illecebrosus, -a, -um**. From Lewis & Short:

> I.full of allurement, very enticing, attractive, seductive (ante- and post-class.): “istoc illecebrosius Fieri nihil potest,” Plaut. Bacch. 1, 1, 54: “sapor,” Prud. adv. Symm. 2, 144: “insidiae,” Amm. 30, 1.—Adv.: illĕcĕ-brōsē , enticingly, attractively.—Comp.: “agi,” Amm. 30, 5, 7 (but not in Plaut. Mil. 3, 2, 36; v. Ritschl ad h. l.).

Now, if "alluring, enticing, attractive, and seductive" isn't what I'd call "sexy", I don't know is! It has the added benefit of being "low class," i.e. it's used in pre-Classical (Plautus from the looks of it) and late Latin authors, but the stodgy "Classical Latin" foregoes it.

Comment: Urbane. Gratias ago.

Answer (score 5):

I know the word "formosa" can apply to someone "well-formed" and therefore "beautiful." Catullus once did a poem describing the word (and a girl named Quintia) in detail.

If your definition of sexy includes things beyond physical beauty, you might consider using the word *formosa,* since that is the context in which Catullus used it.

Answer (score 4):

My first thought was also *venustus -a -um*, *a fortiori* b/c *venus*, after all, = “sex.” The question as to what is the most fitting translation leads to the question what the word (in English) means. My own understanding (only 20 years in the US & Australia) is that it can have different meanings, but often is a tad vague, although probably usually enjoyable.

Answer (score 0):

Something/ someone deemed to be "sexy" is stimulating to the eye/ arousing so verb, "excito" = "rouse up; "wake up"; "raise", "erect"; "arouse" (Oxford) in a present-participle, giving:

"me excitans" = "arousing me".

There are the impersonal verbs: these have only a third-person singular, in each tense and have "it" as their subject e.g. "it is pleasing".

"iuvat" = "it pleases" (+ accusative of the person + infinitive);

"me iuvat eam videre." = "It pleases me to see her.".

"libet" = "it is pleasing" (+ dative + infinitive);

"mihi libuit eam videre." = "It pleased me to see her.".

"placet" = "It pleases" (+ dative);

"mihi placet" = "It pleases me." = "(it is) sexy", would seem to be the best alternative.

EDIT: 2/4/2021:

There are adjectives: "sexualis" = "sexual" & "naturalis" = "sexual" (Oxford) and = "of or pertaining to somebody's nature or qualities" (Wiki).

Comment: The term in English is far less...direct than your proposed translation :)

Comment: @brianpck: Weren't the Romans inclined to be blunt? Have you read Wiki's "Latin Profanity"?

Comment: Iuvat, libet, placet are all way to broad for “sexy” IMHO.